# AWS lambda function with container working locally but not on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, fastapi

i have create a lambda function with container.
The code work well when i test locally.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations"  -d ......
```

But when i push it to ECR and deploy on lambda, it did not worked.
Error is in the first line of code

```
with open(os.path.join('../tmp',video_name), 'wb') as f:
    s3_client.download_fileobj('mybucketname', video_name, f)
```

I dont know where the issue is
Here is complete error

```
START RequestId: 5facecee-e48f-4575-beb8-8afb0710f3e5 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] 2022-08-18T12:07:09.814Z    5facecee-e48f-4575-beb8-8afb0710f3e5    An error occurred running the application.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/mangum/protocols/http.py", line 58, in run
await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
File "/var/task/fastapi/applications.py", line 269, in __call__
await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
File "/var/task/starlette/applications.py", line 124, in __call__
await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
raise exc
File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
File "/var/task/starlette/exceptions.py", line 93, in __call__
raise exc
File "/var/task/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
File "/var/task/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
raise e
File "/var/task/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
await self.app(scope, receive, send)
File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 670, in __call__
await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 266, in handle
await self.app(scope, receive, send)
File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 65, in app
response = await func(request)
File "/var/task/fastapi/routing.py", line 227, in app
raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
File "/var/task/fastapi/routing.py", line 162, in run_endpoint_function
return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
File "/var/task/starlette/concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool
return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
File "/var/task/anyio/to_thread.py", line 31, in run_sync
return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
File "/var/task/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 937, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
return await future
File "/var/task/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 867, in run
result = context.run(func, *args)
File "/var/task/app.py", line 17, in read_item
download_video(video_name)
File "/var/task/botos3.py", line 9, in download_video
with open(os.path.join('../tmp',video_name), 'wb') as f:
END RequestId: 5facecee-e48f-4575-beb8-8afb0710f3e5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
with open(os.path.join('../tmp',video_name), 'wb') as f:
```

to this:

```
with open(os.path.join('/tmp',video_name), 'wb') as f:
```

Only `/tmp` is writeable in the AWS Lambda runtime environment.

Comment: thanks, can you bit explain, why in docker environment i save file in var/tmp and use curl and its working. does when we deploy, the data is moved some where else

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment/question. In your local docker environment the file system is not read-only, so writing to any location is going to work. In AWS Lambda `/tmp` is the only place you can write. That's just part of how the Lambda runtime environment works. So you have to make sure you configure your Docker Lambda functions to comply with that.